# using cout in constructor gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, cout

On a system with ubuntu 13.07, and gcc:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v 
--with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1' 
--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs 
--enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ 
--prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared 
--enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext 
--enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 
--libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ 
--enable-clocale=gnu 
--enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes 
--enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib 
--enable-objc-gc --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl 
--disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check 
--enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 
--with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release 
--build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
```

The following code simply gives a seg-fault:

```
#include <iostream>

void init()__attribute__((constructor));

int main()
{
    return 0;
};
void init()
{
    std::cout<<"test";
}
```

It is expected to print out *test* when constructing before entering main. also tried with *constructor(65530)* and same.
I could absolutely not find out what is wrong. I do not expect a code of so few lines to crash. Also i must mention, that the above code used to work long time (3 years) back with a much older(i do not remember which) version of GCC. Am i making a very obvious mistake?

Following is gdb trace for your kind reference.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b6c131 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7b6c131 in std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7b6c829 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b6cc0f in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_t
#3  0x000000000040079a in init () at test.cpp:12
#4  0x000000000040084d in __libc_csu_init ()
#5  0x00007ffff7730e35 in __libc_start_main (main=0x40077c <main()>, argc=1,
    ubp_av=0x7fffffffd3f8, init=0x4007f0 <__libc_csu_init>,
    fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffd3e8)
    at libc-start.c:219
#6  0x00000000004006b9 in _start ()
```

Comment: Looks like typical problem with static initialization order (i.e., `cout` hasn't been constructed yet when your ctor runs).

Comment: [this bugzilla report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39796) may be of interest.

Comment: @JerryCoffin But `cout` is required to be constructed first. Avind, can you reproduce the problem with an actual constructor, not the GCC-specific feature?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's required to be constructed before *normal* constructors, yes. I'm pretty sure the standard places no requirements on code using gcc's constructor attribute.